# String.Contains(Array?..) - Badword Filter in VB.NET

Tags: vb.net, arrays, string

is there a way to check if a String contains one of the item in array? like this:

```
dim txt as String="badword1 you! you son of a badword2!!"
dim Badwords() as String = {"badword1","badword2","badword3"}
if txt.contains(Badwords()) then
'Whoa.. txt contains some bad vibrations..
end if
```

I could use a loop but is there maybe a faster method how I can check a string if it contains one of the strings in the array?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I think this should do what you want

```
Dim txt As String = "badword1 you! you son of a badword2!!"
Dim Badwords() As String = {"badword1", "badword2", "badword3"}

If Badwords.Any(Function(b) txt.ToLower().Contains(b.ToLower())) Then
    'Whoa.. txt contains some bad vibrations..
    MessageBox.Show("You said a naughty word :P")
End If
```

You'll need to `Import System.Linq`

Comment: Instead of using .ToLower, you can use IndexOf with case insensitive compare -- so
Badwords.Any(Function(b) txt.ToLower().Contains(b.ToLower())) becomes Badwords.Any(Function(b) txt.IndexOf(b, StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase) >= 0)

Comment: upvoted for the comment before you show the message box and for the message itself lol.

Answer (score 6):

A loop is the simplest way.

However, if you are concerned about speed rather than legibility, you could replace the whole array with a single regular expression.

I'm not that good with Basic syntax (a bit rusty), but something like...

```
dim badwords as Regex = new Regex("badword1|badword2|badword3");
if badwords.IsMatch(txt) then
```

If the list of words is fixed, it would be best to make badwords a static. (Is that what they are called in Basic? I mean a variable which is only initialised once in the life of the program, not every time it is used.) There is a Compiled flag you can set in the Regex constructor which would speed things up even further (the expression is compiled when it is created, rather than when it is used).

Regex is found in the System.Text.RegularExpressions namespace.

Comment: close... Matches returns a MatchCollection.

Comment: Sorry - serves me right for typing off the top of my head, instead of checking - is that better?

Comment: Consider adding \b to the beginning and end of each badword to detect word boundaries, as agent-j suggests in his answer. That way you won't detect something like "asexual" when you are looking for "sex".

Answer (score 1):

You can use linq query:

```
    dim txt as String="badword1 you! you son of a badword2!!"
    dim Badwords() as String = {"badword1","badword2","badword3"} 
    dim result as integer = (from l as string in Badwords where txt.contains(l) select l).count
    if result > 0 then  
       'Whoa.. txt contains some bad vibrations..  
    end if
```

Answer (score 0):

A regex could help.

The following code produces this regex: `badword1|badword2|badword3`

```
dim txt as String="badword1 you! you son of a badword2!!"
dim Badwords() as String = {"badword1","badword2","badword3"}
dim regex as new Regex (String.Join("|", Badwords), RegexOptions.IgnoreCase)
if regex.IsMatch(txt) then
'Whoa.. txt contains some bad vibrations..
end if
```

you can improve the logic too, by adding a `\b` word boundary detection at the begining and end of the expression:

The following code produces this regex: `\b(badword1|badword2|badword3)\b`

```
dim regex as new Regex ("\b(" & String.Join("|", Badwords) & ")\b", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase)
```

Edit: improved `\b` portion of answer.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, the use of the REGEX didn't work if the string you were comparing was partially found in the regex string.  For example, and I don't need to use the actual "bad word", but if the string you were comparing to was: "I got bit by a bug and I really got an itch" would produce a true comparison with the use of "IsMatch()" because apparently IsMatch uses a contains type of thing. (SIDE NOTE: in my use, I'm comparing the extension of a file and only care about ones that have the extension vb, xml, or config.  One file that has the extension vbproj produced a match with the Ismatch() function even though my regEx string is "vb|config|xml").

Conversely, if you use this method: If Badwords.Any(Function(b) txt.ToLower().Contains(b.ToLower())) you have the same issue because of the use of contains().  So I modified it to: If Badwords.Any(Function(b) txt.ToLower() = (b.ToLower())) and it worked perfectly.

Thanks for all of the responses to this question, and I hope this works for you now.

Jerry