# How to check if a string contains all characters (in any order) from other string?

Tags: vb.net, winforms, visual-studio-2013, string-comparison

I am going to try to give an example of what I am trying to solve. I think it's the best way to explain the problem.

I have 'for' cycle that generates numbers from X to Y. X is the lower value of the range that I enter in a textbox and Y is the upper value from that range.
For example:
1234 to 4321

So, the software generates values from 1234 to 4321 -> 1234,1235,1236,...,4320,4321.
    For I = 1234 to 4321

I want to add to a listbox only the generated values that contains all the numbers in the lower value textbox.
For example:

```
Lower value textbox = 12344
Generated values:
12344 -> valid because it contains 12344
12395 -> not valid because '5' is not contained in 12344
...
44231 -> valid because it contains 12344
41243 -> valid because it contains 12344
```

I have wrote some code, but I am not coding it well because it's accepting non valid values when the original string (lower value textbox) contains repeated numbers. It works good when there are not repeated values.

I have tried different codes and I have found a link that seems to solve the problem to my question but I have not idea about how it works.
[Check if a string contains all other strings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51563951/check-if-a-string-contains-all-other-strings)

The code I have tried is:

```
        Dim StartNumber As Integer = TextBox_InitialDigit.Text
        Dim FinalNumber As Integer = TextBox_FinalDigit.Text

        Dim AmountOfResults As Integer

        Dim StringOriginal As String = TextBox_InitialDigit.Text

        Dim ArraySubstrings As Char() = StringOriginal.ToCharArray()

        Dim ContainsAll = False


        For I = Convert.ToInt32(TextBox_InitialDigit.Text) To Convert.ToInt32(TextBox_FinalDigit.Text)

            For Each Character In ArraySubstrings
                If I.ToString.Contains(Character) Then
                    ContainsAll = True
                ElseIf Not I.ToString.Contains(Character) Then
                    ContainsAll = False
                    Exit For
                End If
            Next

            If ContainsAll = True Then
                ListBox1.Items.Add(I)
                AmountOfResults += 1
            End If

        Next

        Label_AmountOfResults.Text = "Total results: " & AmountOfResults
```

The above code, as I explained, works ok if the original string (the one I type in textbox) does not contains repeated numbers.

I feel what I'm trying to do is extremely simple to implement but I'm just missing it. Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You should use a List Of Char instead

Comment: What if you initialize `ContainsAll` as `True`, and instead of `ContainsAll=True` use `ContainsAll = ContainsAll And True`. that way it will still be false if it was set to false before

Answer (score 0):

You could verify whether the ordered sequence of numbers that compose the starting value has a correspondance in any of the numbers in the range `[StartNumber] - [EndNumber]`.

Given this range of values:

```
Dim startNum As Integer = 21434
Dim endNum As Integer = 41350
```

Compare the sequence of each generated value in the range and add it to a `List(Of Integer)` if it's a match.
All the matches found will be added to a ListBox in the end.

```
Dim startNChars As Char() = startNum.ToString().ToCharArray().OrderBy(Function(n) n).ToArray()
Dim validResults As New List(Of Integer)()
For i As Integer = startNum + 1 To endNum
    If i.ToString().ToCharArray().OrderBy(Function(n) n).SequenceEqual(startNChars) Then
        validResults.Add(i)
    End If
Next

ListBox1.DataSource = validResults
```